# Erro ao trazer Hora e Data

Tags: java, sql, query

Estou cadastrando no banco de dados MySQL valores como a hora e data.

Código `JAVA`:

```
public String getDataPedido() {

    StringBuilder horaSistema = new StringBuilder();

    GregorianCalendar pegarHora = new GregorianCalendar();
    horaSistema.append(pegarHora.get(GregorianCalendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
    horaSistema.append(":");
    horaSistema.append(pegarHora.get(GregorianCalendar.MINUTE));
    horaSistema.append(":");
    horaSistema.append(pegarHora.get(GregorianCalendar.SECOND));
    return horaSistema.toString();
}

public void setDataPedido(String dataPedido) {
    this.dataPedido = dataPedido;
}

public String getHoraPedido() {
    StringBuilder mesString = new StringBuilder();

    GregorianCalendar pegarMes = new GregorianCalendar();
    mesString.append(pegarMes.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH));
    mesString.append("/");
    mesString.append(pegarMes.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    mesString.append("/");
    mesString.append(pegarMes.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR));

    return mesString.toString();
}

public void setHoraPedido(String horaPedido) {
    this.horaPedido = horaPedido;
}
```

Ele insere a hora e data corretamente, mas quando eu dou um `SELECT` ele não traz a hora registrada no banco e sim a hora atual.

Meu `select` ficou assim:

```
public List<ClubeDoDvdPedidoEmprestimo> selicionarPedidosDeEmprestimo(ClubeDoDvdPedidoEmprestimo clube) throws SQLException{
    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
    sql.append("SELECT codemprestimo, dataemprestimo, horaemprestimo, codigo_socio_solicitou_emprestimo, dvd_codigo, socio_codigo ");
    sql.append("FROM solicitacaoemprestimo ");
    sql.append("WHERE socio_codigo = ? ");
    sql.append("ORDER BY dataemprestimo ASC, horaemprestimo ASC ");

    Connection conexao = FabricaDeConexao.conectar();

    PreparedStatement comando = conexao.prepareStatement(sql.toString());
    comando.setLong(1, clube.getSocio().getCodigo());

    ResultSet resultado = comando.executeQuery();

    List<ClubeDoDvdPedidoEmprestimo> retorno = new ArrayList<>();

    while(resultado.next()){

      final ClubeDoDvdPedidoEmprestimo cdpe = new ClubeDoDvdPedidoEmprestimo();
      cdpe.setCodEmprestimo((resultado.getLong("codemprestimo")));
      cdpe.setDataPedido(resultado.getString("dataemprestimo"));
      cdpe.setHoraPedido(resultado.getString("horaemprestimo"));

      cdpe.setCodigoSocioSolicitouEmprestimo(resultado.getLong("codigo_socio_solicitou_emprestimo"));

      retorno.add(cdpe);
    }
    return retorno;
 }
```

E assim:

```
public void listarSocilitacoesEmprestimo(){
    AdicionarSocioVisao e = new AdicionarSocioVisao();
    e.solicitarCodigoUsuario();

    ClubeDoDvdPedidoEmprestimo find = new ClubeDoDvdPedidoEmprestimo();
    find.setSocio(e);


    try {
        SolicitarEmprestimoDAO dsdao = new SolicitarEmprestimoDAO();
        List<ClubeDoDvdPedidoEmprestimo> resultado = dsdao.selicionarPedidosDeEmprestimo(find);
        for(ClubeDoDvdPedidoEmprestimo d: resultado){
            System.out.println("Código Dvd: "+d.getCodEmprestimo());
            System.out.println("Data Pedido: "+d.getDataPedido());
            System.out.println("Hora Pedido: "+d.getHoraPedido());
            System.out.println("Código do sócio solicitou emprestimo: "+d.getCodigoSocioSolicitouEmprestimo());
            System.out.println("");
        }   
    } catch (SQLException e1) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Só que a hora está vindo atual ou seja o que eu registrei a dois dias atrás esta vindo com a data e hora atual.
Alguém pode me dar uma mão para resolver esse problema?

Answer (score 1):

As suas funções `getDataPedido` e `getHoraPedido` não usam os campos `this.dataPedido` e `this.horaPedido`; portanto, elas não podem retornar o valor que você gravou. Essas funções retornam a hora atual porque [o `GregorianCalendar` funciona usando a hora atual](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#GregorianCalendar()).

De qualquer forma, eu suponho que no futuro você vai precisar calcular os períodos de tempo decorridos entre o empréstimo e a devolução, certo? Neste caso, você deveria estar usando uma classe como a [LocalDateTime](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html), e não uma string, para armazenar essas informações: ela já vem com um método `minus` (pra calcular diferenças temporais).

Comment: Continua trazendo a data atual...

Comment: Pode postar a alteração que você fez nas `get*Pedido`?

Comment: Se você não quer a data atual, você tem que parar de puxar a data atual — a função vai ser simplesmente `public String getDataPedido() { return this.dataPedido; }`.

Comment: Caramba cara, quando eu acho que estou aprendendo eu levo um chute nas canelas... É isso mesmo que você disse, deu certinho... Obrigado...

Comment: Então precisei criar mais dois metodo... esta aqui eles:

Answer (score 0):

Então precisei criar mais dois métodos, estão aqui eles, agora funcionou:

```
public String solicitarDataPedido(){
    LocalDateTime pegarData = LocalDateTime.now();
    LocalDate dataAtual = pegarData.toLocalDate();

    return dataPedido = dataAtual.toString();
}

public String solicitarHoraPedido(){
    LocalDateTime pegarData = LocalDateTime.now();
    LocalDate dataAtual = pegarData.toLocalDate();
    return horaPedido = dataAtual.toString();
}
```